# how to store things in core data and sync with backendless

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, backendless

I need help with the logic of my app. I am new at coding.

Currently, I am coding a expense tracker kind of app. I can add a picture and type in the details in the fields provided.

The current flow is that these data are stored straight away in Backendless. however, when i load my uitableview, it is being populated by fetching the data from backendless immediately, which makes going between the different tabs slow as it has to load from backendless each time i change the view.

While trying to solve that, I would think that storing data in core data would help me populate my table quicker, however, I am not sure of how my core data and backendless should link up. I only have swift knowledge.

Can anyone advise me on how the flow should be like and whether I can do this with backendless api or if I would require other languages in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't require other languages, but the backendless API (at the time of writing) has no support for core data.

Backendless will only deserialise incoming data to plain custom model classes, which you can take a update into core data, but you need to write that logic.

There are a number of mapping libraries which take one object and map it into core data, looking for unique identifiers to prevent duplication in the data store. I can't say that any of them are ideal because you usually want to use a custom class with backendless and a different custom class with core data.

If you don't register a custom class with backendless then it will deserialise to plain arrays & dictionaries and this will likely be easiest to use with mapping libraries. You might need to do a bit of manipulation to get the data into a mappable format...

Comment: Hey, I was looking at firebase, so probably firebase offline capabilities would be the solution to my problem of slow loading?

Comment: You haven't mentioned fire axe or slowness in your question... I'm aware of fire axe but I haven't actually used it.